# Angular JS angular.js:116 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

Hello i am getting this following error in angular js after uploading my code in staging. my code is working fine on local and ngrok also

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module pascalprecht.translate due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'pascalprecht.translate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

maybe in your staging server, you didn't install a language translation file.Please check
Thanks